How to call Wordpress API Internally
I want to call WordPress Page API internally
$request = new WP_REST_Request( 'GET', '/wp/v2/pages/'.$request['id'] );
$response = rest_do_request( $request );
$server = rest_get_server();
$data = $server->response_to_data( $response, false );
$json = wp_json_encode( $data );

but this is not working, Any help would be appreciated!!

The rest_get_server function and the $server variable it returns are not necessary here, and there's no information about what is not working, can you be more specific? E.g. HTTP 500, e.g. empty data, etc. There's also no information about where and when this code is running and how it is triggered. Use the Edit link underneath the question tags to add this information and anything else related to your question
